# How to Read merged table data from microsoft word in C#.net

Tags: c#, office-interop

[image]

This is my code where I reading the table data from ms word file ,
and this worked very well with non-merged table , but i have data in merged table this code not worked

please help....

```
private void Readfiles()
        {
            var word = new Word.Application();
            object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            object path = @"C:\Users\gd-08\Desktop\Маршруты движения (только первый вход и последний выход).rtf";
            object readOnly = true;

var docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);

            //Processing all tables in the documents
            var firstTable = docs.Tables[1];

            var c = firstTable.Rows.Count;


            foreach (Word.Row row in firstTable.Rows)
            {


                List<string> cellValues = new List<string>();
                foreach (Word.Cell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    string cellContents = cell.Range.Text;

                    // add the cell contents to the array, but remove the strange termination character on the end of the data
                    cellValues.Add(cellContents.Remove(cellContents.Length - 1));
                }

                // the first row is the column header

                //AddWordTableRow(cellValues);

            }

            docs.Close();
            word.Quit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to work with table with `for` neither with `foreach` and see were you'll get problem on reading data. Tables at word closer to a multidimensional arrays, so it's hard to work with em.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41973014/how-to-identify-merged-column-and-row-in-word-table/42371294#42371294 This might work for you